# html alignments using kendo and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I did a piece of code.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/mixafehubi/5)

Please see the example bin. the alignments is not proper. Am not sure why the second row is holding only one item.

Comment: Your question is not clear!! Please elaborate!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class='col-md-12'>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachlbl'>Label 1: </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachctrl'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' class='CustkendoTxt' data-id='137' maxlength='255' id='MaxRebatePerClaimant' style='width: 100%;' value='Rebate Tbox' disabled='disabled' /></div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachlbl'>Label 2 Date: </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachctrl'>
        <input type='text' class='CustkendoDpi' data-id='138' id='PostmarkDate' style='width: 100%;' value='2015/04/07' disabled='disabled' /></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-12'>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachlbl'>Label 3: </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachctrl'>
        <textarea type='text' class='form-control' class='CustkendoTxtA' data-id='139' maxlength='255' id='Eligible_Concepts' style='width: 100%; resize: vertical;' disabled='disabled'>Concepts TArea box</textarea></div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachlbl'>Label 4?</div>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachctrl'>
        <select data-role='dropdownlist' class='CustkendoDdl' data-id='213' id='Volume_obtained_from_velocity_reports' style='width: 100%;' disabled='disabled'></select></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-12'>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachlbl'>Label 5: </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachctrl'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' class='CustkendoTxt' data-id='214' maxlength='255' id='RG_Coffee_Value' style='width: 100%;' value='R&G tBox' disabled='disabled' /></div>
</div>

<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachlbl'>Label 6?</div>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachctrl'>
        <select data-role='dropdownlist' class='CustkendoDdl' data-id='215' id='Does_account_require_CEMA_calls' style='width: 100%;' disabled='disabled'></select></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-12'>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachlbl'>Label 7: </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 attachctrl'>
        <select class='CustkendoDdl' data-id='216' id='SodexoA' style='width: 100%;' disabled='disabled'>
            <option value='true' selected='true'>true</option>
            <option value='false'>false</option>
        </select></div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>&nbsp;</div>
```

Try This Code...

[JSbin Link](http://jsbin.com/futuxu/1/)

Comment: Thanks it works well if I put it directly in to my JSBIN. but when i try with my actual website. still the alignment is scattered.  No clue at all.

Comment: It worked like for each col-md-12 we need to surround it as 'row'. Then it worked. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

you gave row class for the all columns.
give a  for each row
like

```
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">

                </div>
<div>

<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">

                </div>
</div>
```